# Can I view the #error message in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have added a lengthy formula to a cell in SSRS, and am now receiving an `#error`. Does this come with a message? Troubleshooting is rather difficult without knowing what is causing the problem.

Comment: When you execute the report from BIDS it should give you an error message.

Comment: If the information you get from BIDS isn't sufficient, a generic #ERROR like that is quite often due to incorrect syntax (easy to rule out), a NULL reference error, or a conversion error (also easy to rule out).  I know this doesn't answer your question, but hopefully it helps with your immediate problem.